# What happens that slow down my specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, FactoryGirl 3.1.0, FactoryGirlRails 3.1.0, Rspec 2.9.0 and RspecRails 2.9.0. In my spec files (about 1300 Examples each file), before each Example runs, I seed the database and create and store few records using factories:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

config.before(:suite) do
  # Cleans the database.
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)

  # Seeds the database.
  load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
end
```

I would like to know why, when I run the `rspec ./spec/models/my_model_spec.rb` command in the Terminal window, my specs ***start to run quickly*** but after a bit (that is, after it has run about 300 Examples) those ***go slowly***. My examples are very simple and almost the same in terms of performance:

```
it "can not update title" do
  @article.update_attribute(:title, "Sample title").should be_false
end
```

After a certain number of tests, Examples like that above take 20/30 seconds to complete (!) and sometime also 60/120 seconds (!!!).

**What happens after run about 300 Examples that slow down my specs also if those Examples are very simple and almost the same in terms of performance? Is there a reason to that behavior?**

---

*Note I*: I tried to run specs in isolation and those are all fast.

*Note II*: When I run specs a `ruby` process in my "Activity Monitor" (I am using a Mac OS X running Snow Leopard 10.6.8) go to use 100% of CPU quickly.

Comment: Try running the slow examples in isolation, and see if they run slower/faster/the same. It's possible those specs just happen to be slow.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - I tried to run specs in isolation and those are all *fast*.

Comment: tests are leaking memory and it starts swapping?

Comment: @Art Shayderov - Can you be more explicit in your question? However I try to respond: There aren't tests in which I use directly memory or I make swapping.

Comment: You don't have to use memory directly (I don't even know what that means, C extensions?). Just not releasing some references to ruby objects will suffice for the process to start increasing his memory footprint. And after it eats all available memory the system starts swapping out memory pages to disk. Just check how much memory the process running your tests consumes. Look in your "Activity Monitor" you mentioned or whatever widget there is for that in Mac Os (`top` command can do that)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your database after every example. Put this in your rspec_helper configure block:

```
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Comment: It seems there isn't difference: it goes slow.